# Archive all marked entries with evil-mode

Tags: org-mode, evil

I recently switched to evil mode and cannot figure out how to archive all marked entries at once.

The way I did it earlier, when I was in a list seeing the candidate entries for archiving I pressed * to mark them all (this works) and then B $ to archive them in bulk. But now B is a motion command and means bo back a word. Is there an evil-mode equivalent of B $? I know that dA stands for $ but I cannot figure out how to do this for all marked entries.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming this is about bulk changes in org-agenda. For me, the Org-Agenda buffers are in evil-mode's emacs-state, meaning that the default emacs key bindings work as expected. You can check what evil state in the mode line: `<N>` for normal state, `<E>` for emacs state.

It might help to put the following into your .emacs:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'org-agenda-mode 'emacs)
```